# error in spache2 000-default.conf file

Tags: server, apache2, configuration, error-handling, configure

I am trying to use apache2 for evil twin access point attack. When I started apache2 service, I got an error:

[image: error message]

This is my config file:

[image: apache config file]

This is my issue, saying that *000-default.config* file has a syntax error on line 39.

Comment: Please don’t add “solved “ to the title. The correct protocol is to accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer that solved your problem. If a current answer is not a solution, then add your own and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `space` between `Directory` and the first quotation mark on the first line of the directive as follows. Also, the last line does not need the directory path.

```
<Directory “/var/www/html">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond%{HTTP HOST} ^www\.(.*)$[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ HTTP://%1/$1 [r=301,l]
RewriteCond%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```